# Cassandra request failure while building secondary index

Tags: cassandra

I know secondary indices are not the recommended way to go in many cases, however I wanted to give it a try for my specific use case.

The total disk space load per machine is 250Gb, replication factor of 2, 2-node cluster.

Nothing fancy, I did

```
create index tst_index on my_data(my_udt_column)
```

The two nodes have been running for the last 6 hours with full RAM - CPU usage and any kind of request involving a `where` clause on that index returns `Operation failed`.

I should add that the column on which the secondary index is built is part of the `partition key` of the table and that it is a UDT (quite simple, two text fields).

This might actually be exposing the weakness of my data model.

Is this normal behaviour? Is it normal that it takes so long to build the index?

Comment: No idea why the index build takes that long. But... as the indexed column is part of your partition key I assume it has a high cardinality? Meaning there exist many different distinct values? If this is the case, you are already in the secondary-index-anti-pattern-space.

Comment: @Ralf Its on the first part of the partition key, where the second part is a timestamp, and then other various things in the clustering part. So I don't think it's that bad.

Comment: Should I restart each nodes in turn to see if Cassandra was stuck building the index?